# JQuery Datepicker minDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datepicker

```
$.post('/scheduler/create', { 
    name: $("#new_schedule_name").val(), 
    start_time: $("#new_schedule_time_start").val(), 
    end_time: $("#new_schedule_time_end").val(), 
    start_date: $("#new_schedule_date_start").datepicker({ minDate: 0, dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val(),
    end_date: $("#new_schedule_date_end").datepicker({ minDate: 0, dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val(),
    playlist: $("#playlists").val(),
    venue: $("#venue").val()
},
```

Hi I am trying to restriict the dates on the datePicker by setting the minDate to 0 but in my app the dates before today can still  be selected I am not sure why this is?

Comment: Why is this a Ruby, or Rails question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a Date object in minDate fields. Try this:

```
$.post('/scheduler/create', { 
    name: $("#new_schedule_name").val(), 
    start_time: $("#new_schedule_time_start").val(), 
    end_time: $("#new_schedule_time_end").val(), 
    start_date: $("#new_schedule_date_start").datepicker({ minDate: new Date(), dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val(),
    end_date: $("#new_schedule_date_end").datepicker({ minDate: new Date(), dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val(),
    playlist: $("#playlists").val(),
    venue: $("#venue").val()
},
```

It will disable days before today.

Comment: That didn't work for me, the reason I set minDate to 0 was because I am following this http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Answer (score 0):

In your code, doesn't it mean that the `datepicker` gets initialized only when your ajax call is made?  I'm not sure if that will work.  Try moving your `datepicker()` initialization outside of `$.post();`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //... rest of your code

    $("#new_schedule_date_start").datepicker({ minDate: '0D', dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
    $("#new_schedule_date_end").datepicker({ minDate: '0D', dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });

    $.post('/scheduler/create', { 
        name: $("#new_schedule_name").val(), 
        start_time: $("#new_schedule_time_start").val(), 
        end_time: $("#new_schedule_time_end").val(), 
        start_date: $("#new_schedule_date_start").val(),
        end_date: $("#new_schedule_date_end").val(),
        playlist: $("#playlists").val(),
        venue: $("#venue").val()
    },

    //... rest of your code
});
```